# Dimension in Naruto where they get stabbed forever

Tags: naruto

I remember this one episode in Naruto when I was a kid, where Naruto's instructor, who had the cloth over one of his eyes throughout most of the series, looked into this one enemy's eyes and got teleported to a dimension where time passed *really* slowly. The person who he looked into the eyes of was there with tons of clones just repeatedly stabbing him with katanas.

I apologize for my lack of knowledge in the subject concerning names, but I vividly remember this one scene and I'd like to know more about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The character who did that was Itachi, Sasuke's brother.

The name of the move was [Tsukuyomi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tsukuyomi).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this happened way before the time skip.

Answer (score 3):

- Naruto's sensei is Kakashi (the guy with the eye patch).
- Kakashi was under a Genjutsu called Tsukuyomi, casted by Itachi.
- Tsukuyomi means the world of the moon god, in Japanese.
- Kakashi actually doesn't go into any other dimension, Tsukuyomi just made him feel that way.
- Once under Tsukuyomi, the caster controls all the senses of the victim, including that of time.

Just being precise. :)